# Hiding NULL column when displaying them in multiple table using javascript express.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, ejs, body-parser

This following is the data in my sql
[image: data]
i am trying to display the data individually into a html page in multiple table form. My expectation is the following
[image]
The NULL row need to exclude in the table.(ignore the caps)

right now i am only able to pass the the entire data into a table. the following is my code in html

```
<% availableItem.forEach(function(parameter1){ %>
    <tr>
    <td> <%= parameter1.Name %> </td>
    <td><%= parameter1.ONE %></td>
    <td><%= parameter1.TWO %></td>
    <td><%= parameter1.THREE %></td>
    <td><%= parameter1.FOUR %></td>
    <% }) %>
```

here is my code in javascript

```
app.get("/display", function (req, res) {
    // query database to get all the appliances
    let sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM table";
    // execute sql query
    db.query(sqlquery, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            res.redirect("/");
        }
        res.render("display.html", { availableItem,: result });

    });

});
```

Do i need to create a loop or something to do this? can anyone advice?

Comment: You add <td> unconditionally now. You must check the value of parameter1.XXX and either add or skip <td> insertion according the value.

Comment: @Akina any idea how can i do that? like the code or sthm

Comment: No, scripting is not my business.